# Number of electrons emitted by the photoelectric effect in a fixed material

Tags: photoelectric-effect

in a material there is a quantity N of electrons, if light (of appropiate wavelenth) hits it, only the valence electrons will be removed from the material (photoelectric effect), how can I calculate the number of electrons removed?
I have seen in the forum that they respond to the number of electrons emitted per second, but they do not involve the material

Answer (score 0):

If you measure the current someway it will give you the number of electrons. Current is measured as Coulombs/sec. And electrons are 1.6E-19 coulombs.

Comment: why was my answer deleted and re-added?